# How can i get IE, Firefox, Chrome to align input textbox the same?

Tags: html, browser

it seems like firefox and chrome default text inputs to center within a fieldset but ie defaults it to left?  How can i make all textbox inputs align left?

Comment: You should post some code or a link to an example so we can see your problem. I don't remember text fields aligning to center by default before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a browser reset. Paste the following as the FIRST css, so either put it in a file called reset.css and include it at the top of the head, or paste it before any other css.

(from http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure here, but CSS is interpreted in a more similar way than JavaScript.  Try CSS.